# Load more random posts on Wordpress using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have 5 random posts on my Wordpress blog sidebar.

I want to create a button that when ever it's clicked, ajax loads 5 more random posts under it.

The problem is that I don't want to get the same random post more than once. 
I don't have an absolute plan about how to do it, I can maybe save posts id names or something like that, but I wonder if there is maybe a better efficient way to do it.

Can somebody help me out with this?

This is the load random posts I have on the sidebar, loads 7 posts:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset' => 1);
    $rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
    $count_rand=0;
    foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li><h2 class="r-h2"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2><p><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'medium'); //the_excerpt(); ?></a></p></li>
    <?php endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the IDs returned for the posts into the WordPress Transient System ( `set_transient()`, `get_transient()`, etc. ) so that you track that visitor's article results. You can then pass these back into your query arguments.

```
$exclude = get_transient( '__my_unique_articles_retrieved' );

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 7,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'offset' => 1,
    'exclude' => $exclude
);
```

By excluding them here, you will make sure you always get your 7 posts. You can also use `delete_transient()` to reset it if you reach a certain count.

For more information on transients in WordPress see here... http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API